# In express js, does too many middleware functions decrease performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm developing (my coworkers and I) an application with `express js` and I've been looking for information for any performance issue when you add too many middleware functions in the server configuration, but I haven't found anything related.

In my case, for instance, I have added the typical middleware: the handler for static resources, a `cookie` parser, a `body` parser, a compressor... and we are thinking to add many more, even custom functions developed by us.

So my question is, is there any moment, any number of handlers, which could cause a performance issue in the application? Or is there anywhere a summary related to this or any tests done by someone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every piece of middleware is a piece of code that gets run for every request.

Each one will degrade performance. Maybe a little, maybe a lot, it depends on what the code does.

Comment: Does every MW piece get run for every request or up until `req.end()` or `req.send()` or whatever?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it depend on at what level the MW is applied?  A middleware applied at the `app.use(mw);` level will probably get used on every request, but at a deeper path, I don't believe it would like: `app.use("/some/deep/obscure/path", mw);`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Since they need to execute sequentially, they might consume resources and impact performance.